# Thread synchonization of a flag

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, data-synchronization

I have a flag that could be read, cleared and set by two threads and I think I need some kind of synchronisations. All the documentation I read focus on resource protection and I'm wondering if there is something more lightweight for my use cases. I'm particularly interested by something that doesn't call down to the kernel every time. I'm currently coding using Objective-C.

Here's my particular use case:

```
 // First thread does the following between 
 // a few times and hundreds of time per second.
 updateBuffer();
 If (displayNeedsUpdate)
    displayBuffer();  
    displayNeedsUpdate = 0;

// Second thread does this 60 times per second:
displayNeedsUpdate = 1;
```

Many thanks!

Comment: An [`os_unfair_lock`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/os_unfair_lock/) is a very performant solution, but is overkill unless you’re doing this very frequently (of the order of thousands of times a second). Generally we’d just make this an `atomic` property and be done with it unless the scenario really demanded something more than that.

Comment: on iOS you could use `CADisplayLink` API instead which is made for those cases retriggering display stuff.

Comment: I agreed re `CADisplayLink`. It’s like a normal timer, but is optimally timed for screen refresh cycles. By the way, you talk about synchronizing this Boolean, but you have to also synchronize the update of the buffer, too. You can’t have the main thread reading from a buffer (presumably for displaying something in the UI) that is simultaneously being updated by the background thread. Use [TSAN](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/412/) to verify the thread safety of this broader process, too.

Comment: @Rob When a boolean is needed to inform about a refresh the concept could be also 2x or tripple buffer which is rotating in only one direction where the increasing of the buffer index is in fact the boolean information.

Comment: Or range(s) of the values that have been updated. Or, in some cases, dispatch source can be great. We probably need to know a bit more about what Yoshi is doing before we make any concrete suggestions. Different problems call for different patterns. The only thing we can say definitively, in the abstract, is that one must avoid data races for everything with which the main thread might interact. The Boolean is not the only concern.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I already use CADisplayLink, dispatch queues and semaphores. I'm just looking for a way to synchronized a flag in the context of my sample code. Thanks!